# How to register an external app in appexchange marketplace

Tags: appexchange, security-review

We have an external .net application which connects into SF using API. We want to sell this app on appexchange.

1. What are steps that need to be taken to list it on appexchange?
2. How does the security review process happen for external applications? which applications are needed to be run?

Do we need to share the code? How does SF check for vulnerabilities in external applications?

i did take a look at the foll links
https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout&oldid=49366

https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/AppExchange_Security_Requirements_Checklist

but i couldnt really find on how to list external applications. If any one could explain it in simple terms would be great, specially for security review.